# Getting filtered results by JQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I tried to use autocomplete with json, but I always get the complete data. I expect filtered data from the user input.

**JS:**

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: "/script.php",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var url = ui.item.id;
        if(url != '#') {
            location.href = '/blog/' + url;
        }
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$result = $paed_db->prepare('SELECT data FROM table');
$result->execute();
$a_json = array();
while($data = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $a_json_row["value"] = $data->data;
    array_push($a_json, $a_json_row);
}

$json = json_encode($a_json);
print $json;
exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQueryUI does nothing to filter the results - you need to do the search in your query on the PHP script. JQueryUI sends the user input via a GET request, so you can access it using:

```
$search = $_GET['term'];
```

(See http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

So you can then use that $search variable in your prepared query to select the appropriate rows from the table. For example, if you had a column called name that you wanted to search on:

```
$result = $paed_db->prepare('SELECT data FROM table WHERE name LIKE :search');
$result->execute(array('search' => '%'.$search.'%'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are always returning everything. Look at your query. You don't filter the query by the user input from the autocomplete. The user's input is passed automatically as a URL param called term. Your query should use that to filter the data. See more here: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source